# ssl is not working in 2 pages of my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ssl

This problem is for one of my client's site. Its loading slowly on mobiles. My senior said it's because ssl is not working in 2 pages. How to check whether the ssl is working and how to solve this issue

Comment: Hello: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Loading slow of the site is not related to SSL. It might hamper those two pages only. It may be due to Mixed Content Issue. It may help you : https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-mixed-content-warning/

Answer (score 1):

I got it what you want. Just follow what I'll tell. It'll be easy as it was never. I recommend you to go with a free plugin. Head over to **Plugins > Add New** and search for **Really Simple SSL**. The plugin is specially designed for SSL related issues. After you have installed the plugin, Activate it.

Now, you just need to configure some settings. First of all, you'll see a floating information box on your WordPress admin dashboard. A button will say: *Go Ahead, Activate SSL*, just click that button and your site will be SSL ready (not fully yet). What you need is a valid SSL Certificate.

Then go to **Settings > SSL**, and then Settings from the above navigation menu beside Configuration. There you will see an option saying **Enable WordPress 301 Redirection to SSL**, put it on. Done!

Now, you may want to check any SSL issues with your content and the site. For that, go to **Scan for Issues** tab from the above menu again.

I hope the above method was easy for you and helped.

Tell me if you want a proper explanation with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Check  URL of the site is like(https://): https://stackoverflow.com/ 
Not like(http://)  http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That's how I  checked. How to know ssl is working or not?

Comment: Contact your host provider is SSl enable on your site or not 
another option you can change the http url to https and aftter https url Change Check site is  working Fine or not if it working after https  then your site is SSl enable.

Answer (score 0):

check your images URL in your page. Mostly forget changing image URLs is cause of SSL broken issue. But if your mobile pages are slow that does not affect so much. Try gtmetrix to find your timings to which one is slow and try to fix it.